# Is this a probability on $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Given the domain $\Omega = [0,1]$ and the correpsonding Borelian $\sigma$-algebra $A = B([0,1])$ I have to find a probability measure $P$ such taht $(\Omega, A,P)$ is a probability space. I think I have found such an example but I'm not completely sure:

> Let $P(\{x\}) := \begin{cases} 1 & x=1 \\ 0 & x\neq 1\end{cases}$ or equivalently $P(X) := \begin{cases} 1 & 1 \in X \\ 0 & x\not\in X\end{cases}$ for $X \in A$.

I checked the axioms:

- $P$ is a well defined function $P:A \to [0,1]$.
- $P(\Omega) = 1$ since $1 \in [0,1]=\Omega$.
- $P$ is obviously $\sigma$-additive

But still I have the feeling that something is wrong. So can you tell me whether this is correct or I did something wrong?

Comment: Correct, but the first definition doesn't determine $P$ (e.g. for uncountable subsets), so it's better to stick with the second one.

Comment: Ah right, because $\{x\}$ is not necessarily in $A$ (in our case it is). Feel free to add your comment as an answer such that I can accept it!

Comment: Then I will. Just you're certainly aware it is recommended to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, since there can always be a better one! BTW I'm not sure what you mean with $\{ x \}$ not necessarily being in $A$. It is, because $A$ are the Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct with one remark: the first definition does not determine $P$ even if we try to naturally extend the definition using countable additivity:

$$P(B) = \bigcup_{b \in B} P( \{ b \} )$$

since it only works for countable $B$, leaving $P(B)$ undefined for uncountable $B \in A$.

The second definition is correct and should be the one used.